# Order by (chained) column which can be null

Tags: hibernate, null, sql-order-by, hql

I am currently encountering a problem with Hibernate where I create a HQL statement automatically which looks like

```
FROM table ORDER BY a.b ASC NULLS LAST
```

My intention was to order all entries by `a.b` and setting all entries where `a` or `b` is `NULL` to the end of the table. Hibernate does not complain about the statement, but just ignores all entries where `a` is `NULL` already. I experimented with setting:

```
FROM table ORDER BY NULLIF(a.b, NULL) ASC NULLS LAST
```

and again, Hibernate does not complain but again ignores all entries where `a` is `NULL`.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Btw, In HQL, you don't query tables. The query is actually `FROM entity`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the answer, I found a different solution which was easier to implement. I now create a request as follows:

```
FROM table ORDER BY a ASC NULLS LAST, a.b ASC NULLS LAST
```

For me, this works for any dimensions of chains as long as these orders are ok. This is much easier for me to implement since the query is generated automatically. However, thank's for the advice. I tried it and your solution works fine as well but would require me to adjust my overall setup.

Comment: I kind of don't understand why it works for you. It doesn't for me (hibernate still makes a join underneath and throws away rows where a is null)

Comment: Might be DB dependant. I used Oracle 11 at that time.

Answer (score 2):

I guess a is a property of type table_two, and this property is defined with a many-to-one relation or sth. similar.

You order over a column which is not a member of table but of the related table_two. Sql can't do this directly, and Hibernate does this by generating a join between table and table_two. This join generated by Hibernate is a normal join, not an outer join, so the select does not fetch the rows which do not have a related entry in table_two.

You can solve the problem by defining the outer join manually. Something like this should work:

```
FROM table t
   LEFT OUTER JOIN t.a u
   ORDER BY u.b ASC NULLS LAST
```

Comment: I think it should be `left join`. `outer` is not HQL.

Comment: `left outer join` and `left join` is the same. The latter only is an abbreviation for the first.

Comment: Which is true in SQL. I thought that in HQL, there is only `left join`. I may be wrong ...

Comment: Yes, you are.  http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins

Answer (score 1):

I've just had the same issue, I performed a left outer join ... I have a `Cost` and `Order` domains, the Order property is a nested relationship instance; this could potentially be `NULL`.  For extra clarity, i.e.:

```
class Cost { 
    User  owner 
    Order order 
    etc...
}

Cost.executeQuery('SELECT c FROM Cost AS c LEFT OUTER JOIN c.order AS o WHERE c.owner = ? ORDER BY o.orderNumber ASC, c.id DESC' , cost_qry_params, params)
```

You can put your pagination/sorting information in the params... Hope this helps someone :)